# How can I detect if scp service is available at remote host with out sending the file?

Tags: perl, scp

Could you please suggest a way to detect if the scp service is available on a server without the need for an account and/or password?

I am trying to figure out how to tell if

```
 Net::SCP->new( "hostname", "username" );
```

function fails to connect to remote because of service is unavailable at remote host
or because of authentication failure.

Answer (score 6):

sshd would be running on port 22. Telnet to it to see if it is responding.

To check the server without coding something up, at the command line, type:

```
telnet host.example.com 22
```

If the ssh service is available, the response will look something like this:

```
Trying host.example.com...
Connected to host.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
```

If not, you'll see:

```
Trying host.example.com...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

Net::SCP doesn't use passwords unless you're using the interactive mode, it uses RSA or DSA keys. At the point you use get() or put(), those functions will return a true or false on success or failure.

You might wish to check out Net::SCP::Expect instead if you need to use passwords instead of key authentication. The perldoc for both modules has good examples to follow.

Answer (score 1):

use Net::SSH2 or Net::OpenSSH instead of Net::SCP

Answer (score 0):

Chadwick has it correct above, but when you think it should work and sshd is running, then check the following:

1. Route OK? Try

   ```
   ping host.example.com
   ```
2. Is hosts.allow file on host.example.com set to allow the connection?
   It has to be able to resolve the incoming connection if you use DNS
   names.
3. Is there a firewall running on host.example.com? Try

   ```
   iptables -L
   ```

   on Linux or check the firewall on Windows.